# Dispatched event not firing in parent aura component

Tags: lightning-experience, aura, lightning-web-components

I am following [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_sending_to_aura_components) guide to communicate between my LWC and my aura component. But for some weird reason it still doesnt work.

**myComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasSObjectName,lightning:actionOverride" >    
    <ui:scrollerWrapper class="scrollerSize" aura:id="scrollerTop">
        <!-- Other code -->
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    <!-- My test Lightning Web Component -->
    <c:helloworld onfilterchange="{!c.handleEvent}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**myComponentController.js**

```
({
    handleEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("BACK!");
    }
});
```

**helloworld.js**

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        window.addEventListener("message", this.fireEvent, false, {
            once: true
        });

    }



    fireEvent(event){
        const filterChangeEvent = new CustomEvent('filterchange', {
            detail: { "HELLO": 'TEST' }
        });
        try{
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if(data.ap_mobile){

                // Fire the custom event
                this.dispatchEvent(filterChangeEvent);
                console.log("Event Fired!");
            }
        }catch(error){
            console.log("Error Parsing");
        }
    }
}
```

The `Event Fired!` text is shown but thats it, the controller doesnt fire the `handleEvent` function at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wha tis the cotnext, LEX or communities? what exactly is triggering the action?

Comment: @glls The context is LEX

Comment: I am testing this on the salesforce one emulator app on google chrome

Comment: can you try <c:helloWorld  and see ..

Comment: `<c:helloWorld />` doesnt exist

Comment: @glls I have the event listener that triggers manually by me doing `window.postMessage(data, "*")` this triggers the eventListener for `message`

Comment: do you see any errors in your console when doing so?

Comment: Not a single error

Answer (score 4):

As another possible issue, you have a naming convention error.

LWC automatically [forces the LWC Class name to Pascal Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_javascript), but you have a dueling format right now:

- LWC class of `HelloWorld` <- this is Pascal Case
- LWC JS of `helloworld.js` <- This is not, it should be helloWorld, capital W.
- Template of `helloworld.html` (embedded in aura)

I just tried this and it works fine, notice the naming convention of the LWC file and its class. Everything is lowercase.

**helloworld.js**

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Helloworld extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const payload = {
      "hello": "test"
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('filterchange', {
        detail: { payload }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**AuraListener.cmp**

```
<c:helloworld onfilterchange="{! c.handleChange }"></c:helloworld>
```

**AuraListenerController.js**

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
  let payload = event.getParam("payload");
  console.log(payload.hello) // outputs test
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue was where I was creating the event from

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        window.addEventListener("message", this.fireEvent, false, {
            once: true
        });

    }
}
```

Should be...

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        super()
        window.addEventListener("message", this.fireEvent, false, {
            once: true
        });

    }
}
```